# How to receive mouseDragged events for my JTable

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, mouselistener

I'm trying to write a customized Drag and Drop behavior for a JTable, but can't receive `MOUSE_DRAGGED` events. I guess the problem is the native DnD operation consumes the event (as mantioned in `mouseDragged`'s javadoc: `"Due to platform-dependent Drag&Drop implementations, MOUSE_DRAGGED events may not be delivered during a native Drag&Drop operation. "`), but I'm looking for a way to disable it, or work around it.

This is an SSCCE demonstrating the problem:

```
public class DragAndDrop {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(
                new JTable(
                        new Object[][] {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}, 
                        new Object[] {"one", "two", "three"}) 
                {{

                        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                            @Override
                            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                                System.out.println("mouseDragged");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                                System.out.println("mousePressed");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                                System.out.println("mouseReleased");
                            }

                        });
                }}
        );

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- only mistake by using proper Mouse(Xxx)Listener and with combine with MouseAdapter doesn't crying with/for exception
- you added MouseListener, proper could be MouseListener and together with MouseMotionListener, you can to split those two Listener to two separate code block for (another possible mistakes) TransferHandler

.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class DragAndDrop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JTable(new Object[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}},
                new Object[]{"one", "two", "three"}) {
            {
                addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("mouseDragged");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("mousePressed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("mouseReleased");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

with

```
run: 
mouseDragged mouseDragged mouseDragged 
mouseDragged mouseDragged 
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 11 seconds)
```

Comment: BTW, I left both sets of methods inside the same `MouseAdapter`, and just registered it as both `MouseListener` *and* `MouseMotionListener`.